# Default value in OUTER JOINS instead of NULLs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Once doing LEFT JOIN on two tables I receive NULL values for those absent in the first table.

I am doing consolidation on the ranking table.

Is it possible to set those NULLs to MAX+1 value in the joined value column?

See example:

```
TABLE 1:
Key_1, Key_2, Key_3, RankA
Europe, England, London, 2
Europe, Germany, Berlin, 1
Europe, France, Paris, 3
Europe, Spain, Madrid, 4
Europe, Portugal, Lisbon, 5
Europe, Norway, Oslo, 7

TABLE 2:
Key_1, Key_2, Key_3, RankB
Europe, England, London, 1
Europe, Germany, Berlin, 3
Europe, Spain, Madrid, 2
Europe, Norway, Oslo, 4

Expected result:
Key_1, Key_2, Key_3, RankA, RankB
Europe, England, London, 2,  1
Europe, Germany, Berlin, 1,  3
**Europe, France, Paris, 3,  5**
Europe, Spain, Madrid, 4,  2
**Europe, Portugal, Lisbon, 5,  5**
Europe, Norway, Oslo, 7,  4
```

It could be a better idea to do the ranking after the tables are joined but currently it is done in the calculation procedure which I want to keep this way for a short term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following: For the last column, instead of `table2.rankb`,use

```
isnull(table2.rankb,1+max(table2.rankb) over (order by table2.rankb))
```

Comment: Need to add the closing bracket to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `left join` with `apply` :

```
select . . ., 
       isnull(t2.rankb, t22.max_rank) as rankb
from t1 left join
     t2 
     on . . . outer apply
     ( select max(t22.RankB) + 1 as max_rank
       from t22 
     ) t22;
```

However, `cross join` is more appropriate :

```
select . . ., 
       isnull(t2.rankb, t22.max_rank) as rankb
from t1 left join
     t2
     on . . . cross join
     (select max(t22.RankB) + 1 as max_rank from t2 as t22
     ) t22
```

Answer (score 1):

For exacly solution with searching max value once:

```
DECLARE @OverMax INT;

SELECT @OverMax = ISNULL(MAX(RankB), 0) + 1
FROM TABLE_2;

SELECT 
    t1.Key_1, 
    t1.Key_2, 
    t1.Key_3, 
    t1.RankA, 
    ISNULL(t2.RankB, @OverMax) RankB
FROM TABLE_1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2
    ON t1.Key_1 = t2.Key_1
    AND t1.Key_2 = t2.Key_2
    AND t1.Key_3 = t2.Key_3;
```

For only sorting:

```
SELECT 
    t1.Key_1, 
    t1.Key_2, 
    t1.Key_3, 
    t1.RankA, 
    t2.RankB
FROM TABLE_1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2
    ON t1.Key_1 = t2.Key_1
    AND t1.Key_2 = t2.Key_2
    AND t1.Key_3 = t2.Key_3
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t2.RankB IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, t2.RankB
```